# Which Pen Is Best For Writing/Signing Important Documents?

Tags: style, editing

Regular pens or gel ink pens? What do you say?

Comment: For signatures you need ink which is not easily erasable (ball pen is a good choice). The remaining part of this question is highly subjective.

Comment: I thought pen questions were already deemed off topic.

Comment: @Ralph Well, pens as writing tools are on topic, but I'm not sure that's being asked here.  It seems like it's more financial or legal -- i.e. what is most resistant to tampering -- or possibly scrapbooking -- i.e. what will remain beautiful after years of age and handling.

Comment: ...If @Boris_yo really meant to ask about writing, I'd encourage him to re-submit something worded better.  I'd start by clarifying what is menat by "regular pens" as there are rollerballs, ball points, dip pens, fountain pens, felt-tip pens, porous-point pens, and so on available in addition to gel pens. Then, I'd try to find a way to more clearly relate the question to writing and make it more objective, e.g. "How do I keep my longhand drafts/notes as clear as they were when written? Is ball point, gel, or some other type of pen more resilient in the face of age, spills, UV, etc.?"

Comment: @HedgeMage I'd consider Pen questions off-topic just as this question was considered off-topic: http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/1033/361

Comment: @Ralph That question was off-topic because it was about computing equipment (a printer) which is already covered on Super-User.  I can't think of another Stack site that would handle questions about writing instruments in this context.